# Raster rotation on QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

How can I rotate a raster layer (global land-mass) to make the 180 deg longitude the center of the map (using QGIS)? 'rotate' function in R is simple but not accurate. Raster has 'longlat' projection and WGS84.

Comment: You can do it with projected coordinates, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79093/escape-the-cut-of-western-eastern-hemispheres/79103#79103 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181526/polygons-across-international-dateline-180-180-longitude. See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/how-to-reproject-raster-from-0-360-to-180-180-with-cutting-180-meridian

Answer (score 2):

Based on [How to reproject raster from 0 360 to -180 180 with cutting 180 meridian](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/how-to-reproject-raster-from-0-360-to-180-180-with-cutting-180-meridian), a possible solution using GDAL is:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs WGS84 bluemarble.tif 180.tif  -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 --config CENTER_LONG 180
```