# Fix distortions when reprojecting cshapes world maps?

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, r, distortion

I am using the `cshapes` package in R as a source of historically accurate country borders. While the default WGS 84 maps plot fine, I would like to reproject the maps. This introduces some distortions that I'm guessing are related to underlying issues in the map data:

1. **How can I correctly reproject and plot a `cshapes` map in R?**
2. **If the distortion issue really is related to underlying map data issue, how can I fix these?**

Here is a default WGS 84 map, which looks fine:

[image]

But when attempting to plot a Robinson projected map, distortion near 180 longitude:

[image]

The associated [shapefile is here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/chuxm560tj2jvi7/AACk76sGRe4TuyyFLzIe3gsRa?dl=0).

I created these maps in R using the following code:

```
library("cshapes")
library("ggplot2")
library("rgdal")

# Get map data and plot with default CRS (WGS 84)
wmap <- cshp(date=as.Date("2012-06-30"))
wmap_df <- fortify(wmap)

ggplot(wmap_df, aes(long,lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_polygon() + 
  labs(title="World map (longlat)") + 
  coord_equal()

ggsave("~/Desktop/map1.png", height=4, width=7)

# Reproject to Robinson
wmap_robin <- spTransform(wmap, CRS("+proj=robin"))
wmap_df_robin <- fortify(wmap_robin)
ggplot(wmap_df_robin, aes(long,lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_polygon() + 
  labs(title="World map (robinson)") + 
  coord_equal()

ggsave("~/Desktop/map2.png", height=4, width=7)

# Export original map data
writeOGR(wmap, ".", "wmap_wgs84", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Additional info:

1. Duplicate of [original question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607657/distortions-when-reprojecting-cshapes-world-map), someone over there suggested I try to get help here.
2. I know there are many other sources for country borders, but I'm tied to `cshapes` for historically accurate maps.
3. I'm using GDAL 1.11.3, installed via homebrew, and Proj4 4.9.2. I built `rgdal` from source against these.
4. Part of my problem is that I don't know what terms to even search for for this issue, any help would be great.

There is a [similar question here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151601/lines-on-reprojected-sp-objects-with-mollweide-projection), which indicates that the problem is that Russia and a Pacific island exceed 180°E.  However, the answers provided are either implemented in QGIS, not R, or are based on removing vertices, which is problematic for me because I want to eventually use the maps to make thematic maps (i.e. countries with color fill).

Comment: This is related problem, but not a duplicate question. The problem looks the same, but the solution is different.

Comment: Whether an answer is accepted or not is more or less irrelevant because many users do not learn to accept before leaving the site.  Highly upvoted answers are usually far more valuable.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that, I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `raster::crop` to remove nodes that are just smaller than -180 or larger than 180

```
library(cshapes)
library(raster)

wmap <- cshp(date=as.Date("2012-06-30"))
w <- crop(wmap, extent(-180, 180,-90,90))
w_robin <- spTransform(w, CRS("+proj=robin"))
plot(w_robin)
```