# Reprojecting a shapefile with ogr2ogr when a line is crossing the international date meridian

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr

I have a line shapefile with a local transverse mercator projection
("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=50 +lon_0=172.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs") and I want to reproject it into EPSG:4326 with ogr2ogr.
The line feature is crossing the international date meridian, as you can see in the image.
[image: Input line]
This particular situation seems to be a problem for ogr2ogr. In fact, the reprojected output line is crossing the entire world, and this is clearly wrong.
[image: Output line]

This is the command I used for the reprojection:

ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" track_linedate_pr.shp track_linedate.shp -t_srs EPSG:4326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way to display the shape properly than to cut it between 179.9°E and -179.9° (W). I described a workflow for the cutting here:

[QGIS display world country shape files centered on pacific ocean using Robinson, Miller Cylindrical or other projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70411/qgis-display-world-country-shape-files-centered-on-pacific-ocean-using-robinson)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-wrapdateline` flag with ogr2ogr to split the geometry automatically at the dateline

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the sinusoidal grid shown in https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/253938/5256.