# Joining 2 vector pieces of one country into one vector polygon using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, merge

How to eliminate seam on meridian 168W. Seam is on Russia and Antarctica?

[image]

I have done my projection in this way:

[QGIS display world country shape files centered on pacific ocean using Robinson, Miller Cylindrical or other projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70411/qgis-display-world-country-shape-files-centered-on-pacific-ocean-using-robinson)

Comment: Welcome.  Please take the tour here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour. You may want to add some screenshots and more explanation in order to get a good answer--it's difficult to tell from your question if you are having issues with the projection or the actual merging of the data.