# QGIS incorrectly saving polygon with custom CRS, while correctly projecting it on-the-fly

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I'm splitting a land polygon up in order to shift the centering of the projection to the Pacific ocean. I manage to successfully cut up the original polygon on the 22 meridian, and it looks fine when I do an on-the-fly reprojection with my custom CRS:

[image: OTF polygon projection]

But appears to be shifting slightly when actually *saving* the polygon with the same CRS:

[image: saved polygon projection]

My CRS is using this proj4 string: `+proj=eqc +lon_0=-158 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +lon_wrap=-158`

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: this is caused by features overlapping the -156+180 = 24 degree east meridian (this is more commonly seen with crossing the 180W antimeridian, but is different as you've shifted the map

Comment: @StevenKay that's actually a typo on my part :x fixed my original post

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70411/qgis-display-world-country-shape-files-centered-on-pacific-ocean-using-robinson. I used a sphere instead of an ellipsoid, a cut polygon 0.2 degrees wide, and no `+lon_wrap` option.

Answer (score 6):

These 'artifacts' are a well known problem, and are usually the result of polygons crossing the antimeridian (180 degrees e/w)
The go-to fix for this is usally **ogr2ogr** with the wrapdateline option.

But that won't help you. In your case, you're using an offset around  -156. This means that any feature crossing 24E meridian (-156+180 = 24) is giving you problems.

To fix this, I removed a thin strip either side of 24E.

I started with Natural Earth data, and left off projection (for now), and just used WGS84.

To draw the 24E meridian, I used the **QuickWKT plugin** and added the following as a new layer...

```
LINESTRING (24 -90,24 90)
```

That draws a single line along the length of the 24E meridian.

Next, I manually digitised a **polygon scratch layer**, adding two polygons, one to each side of the line, and a hemisphere in size, but hugging the line as close as possible. (Note the quality of the line drawing here...)

[image]

You should probably do that with the QuickWKT plugin too, to get more precision - it involves more typing and I wanted a quick test :)

Next, I used **clip** to clip my original shapefile to the layer with the two polygons. This cuts out a thin strip around the 24E meridian...

[image]

finally, I applied OTF projection using your custom CRS - and the fixed result.

[image]

Comment: Ah, oh no! Wish I'd gotten back to my computer sooner before you did all this work for me. My proj4 string was actually around 158; I just pasted the wrong one in (with 156) after doing some experimentation.

Comment: you'll see the same issue with 158 (i do anyway) - just change 24 to 22 . If you got it to work without doing this let me know how - i'd not found the lon_wrap feature in proj4 until quite recently :) (come to think of it, that might explain why Madagscar seems slightly offset...)

Comment: So I did all the steps you did (essentially) - WKT polygon strip around 22; Vector > Geoprocessing > Difference w land as my input layer and WKT strip as the difference layer; OTF reproject. Up til that point everything looks great. The problem arises after I save my resulting polygon with the same custom CRS - the saved polygon is all wonky but the OTF one is fine :(

Comment: thanks for clarifying... just loaded the saved layer from my (now discarded) project (saved using the custom proj4 crs) and the lon_wrap value isn't showing up in the layer metadata. that might be the problem

Comment: Hmm. Do you know how to fix that? I find the proj4 documentation a bit confusing.

Comment: ok, tried again with a fresh pair of eyes :) it works fine when projected (QGIS 2.18.2). Make sure you choose the correct CRS when saving, when I tried this I picked the one which was shifted off by 2 degrees and saw the same thing as your first screenshot. Give the CRSes obvious names to make them easier to pick out.

Comment: You know, after quitting & shutting down the computer for the end of the day and then coming back today, I re-saved the polygon again and it was fine. I think after fiddling around with the CRS, you may need to actually *restart* QGIS before saving a polygon with it. So the CRS changes work fine for OTF, but QGIS needs to be restarted for it to save correctly?? Bug, maybe? I have them all well-named so (I'm fairly sure) I was choosing the correct one each time!