# Transforming a shapefile from EPSG:3338 to EPSG:4326?

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, ogr2ogr, antimeridian

I'm trying to transform [this shapefile](http://www.asgdc.state.ak.us/?#65) from EPSG:3338 (Alaska Albers) to EPSG:4326.

When I display the file in EPSG:3338 in QGIS it looks as you'd expect:

[image]

But when I display it in EPSG:4326 I see all kinds of problems:

[image]

And when I export it as EPSG:4326 I see the same problem. This happens both whether I export it in QGIS, or use ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -s_srs EPSG:3338 -t_srs EPSG:4326 .   
  mv_oil_and_gas_basin_py.geojson mv_oil_and_gas_basin_py.shp
```

How can I transform this file to EPSG:4326 without getting problems around the international dateline?

Comment: you'll need to use the technique described in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70411/qgis-display-world-country-shape-files-centered-on-pacific-ocean-using-robinson to put a break in at 180

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `-wrapdateline` in [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to split the polygons at the anti meridian (as the dateline in fact misses Alaska).

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:3338 -t_srs epsg:4326 -wrapdateline output.shp mv_oil_and_gas_basin_py.shp
```

Once I fixed the 4 invalid polygons I get this:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't solved the problem - still looks the same in QGIS. (I tried: `ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:3338 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -wrapdateline output_file.shp mv_oil_and_gas_basin_py.shp`. Trying without the `t_srs` option produced a warning.)

Comment: It would work if all the polygons were valid.

Comment: It doesn't, sorry - I just tried importing the shapefile to PostGIS and running `ST_MakeValid` on all the polygons, and I get the same result.

Comment: Thanks! What worked for me in the end was to import it to PostGIS without reprojecting, then run `ST_MakeValid`, then export it using ogr2ogr to reproject to 4326 on the fly, with the `-wrapdateline` option.

Comment: I guess that `wrapdateline` produces the invalid geometries during cutting, while my workaround from the linked question does not.

Comment: @AndreJ - no there are 4 invalid geometries in the downloaded dataset, mostly reversed winding order