# Graphical error while reprojecting Shapefile with QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, reprojection-mathematics

I'm trying to retroject Natural Earth's Shapefile of the world (Admin 0 – Countries on this page: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/).

Here's the original Shapefile in QGIS 3.4.1:

[image]

Reprojected in Robinson World, centered at Long 0:

[image]

All seem good. However, when I try to reproject centred at a different longitude (say Montréal at -73.3), here's what happens:

[image]

The polygons aren't sliced at the edge of the new map, and the software is confused as to where polygons start and end.

What's a good way to deal with these problems?

Comment: You have to manually slice the polygons before you can re-project them centered around a different longitude. I couldn't find it, but I know this question has been asked on GIS SE before and has a helpful answer. Try looking for questions with the terms "meridian" and "projection".

Comment: [This one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70411/qgis-display-world-country-shape-files-centered-on-pacific-ocean-using-robinson) @csk ?